# Equivalent to .append for a list element

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div id="list">
</div>
```

and then:

```
$('#list').append('a<br>');
$('#list').append('b<br>');
$('#list').append('c<br>');
```

But what I would like is:

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Q: How can I append to an unordered list in jQuery using the DOM and not using .html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `appendTo()`: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
var list = $('#list');

$('<li></li>').appendTo(list).text('List item 1');
```

You can then use chaining to define additional properties such as text and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = $('<ul id="list"/>');
list.append('<li>content</li>');
```

Comment: The variable just make things slower and is not necessary if it's not gonna be re-used somewhere else in the script.

Comment: Indeed, but from his example, he wants to add more than one element. So this solution is kinda faster than appending elements to existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do:

```
$('#list').append('<li>Item #1</li><li>Item #2</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.append()` method is still correct. The question is *what* are you appending?

Since `#list` is a `<ul>`, you need to `.append()` `<li>` elements.

Of course, if the `#list` is empty, and you're appending several at once, you could always use `.html()` or `.innerHTML` instead.

```
$('#list').html("<li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>");
```

or

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>";
```

...which would be fastest.

Then use `.append()` thereafter for additional elements.